# Height of projectile above the inclined plane and above the horizontal.

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I am trying to work out the maximum height of a projectile above the incline plane and above the horizontal plane but I am not sure how to do this.  I have worked out all the equations of motion, $ax, sx, ux, vx$ and $ay, vy, uy , sy$ but I am not sure how to find the different heights.

Could someone give me a hint as to what I need to do. Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to work out the maximum height in general.  That is, you take final velocity = 0, because when the projectile reaches it's maximum height, it's velocity is temporarily 0, as it changes from moving upwards to moving downwards.

Comment: Yes, I know to let $vy = 0$ then use the time value from that to find $sy$ but that is only for max height above the horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let coordinates be such that x=0 at the beginning of the incline.  That is, when the incline height is 0, x=0, and for all x values greater than 0, then incline height is greater than 0.

We also know the coordinates of the max height of the ball, which we will call $(x_{max},y_{max})$.

Let us first find the height of the incline when $x=x_{max}$.  To do this we simply use the tan rule.

$\tan\theta = \frac{y_i}{x_{max}}$

I have used $y_i$ to represent the height of the incline when the x-coordinate is $x_{max}$ (the x-position of the ball's max height).  Also $\theta$ represents the angle of the incline.

Re-arranging gives,

$y_i = x_{max}\tan\theta$

Now the height difference, $h_d$ between the ball and the incline is therefore:

$h_d = y_{max} - x_{max}\tan\theta$

But this is just the vertical height difference between the ball and the incline.  If we want the perpendicular components however, our calculations are not over yet.

By drawing a diagram, a triangle can be formed from the ball's vertical distance from the incline, and the ball's perpendicular distance from the incline.  An analysis of the triangle shows that we can work out the perpendicular distance using the cos rule.

$\cos\theta = \frac{D_p}{h_d}$, where I have defined $D_p$ as the perpendicular distance between the ball and the incline.

Re-arranging gives,

$D_p = h_d\cos\theta = (y_{max} - x_{max}\tan\theta)\cos\theta = y_{max}\cos\theta - x_{max}\sin\theta$

Therefore the answer to your question is,

$y_{max}\cos\theta - x_{max}\sin\theta$, where $(x_{max},y_{max})$ is the coordinates of the ball's max height.